# Qt BLE advertising gives "advertising error", "HCI command disallowed"

Tags: qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, qt-creator, hci

I wanted to use Qt and Qt creator to advertise on my laptop with BLE. When I start the application example "heart-rate server", it gives the error "advertising error". Btmon shows the error "HCI command disallowed".
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/433yc.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJzqQ.png)

I am running as root.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/36kN1.png

I’m using Qt version 5.15.2. Trying it on a linux laptop with ubuntu version 22.04.2

When I tried to advertise with bluetoothctl "advertise on" in the terminal. It did work and all commands are allowed in btmon.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems to me not very wise to use your own HCI commands and bypass the Bluetooth stack. Have you tried using the BlueZ tools (e.g. `bluetoothctl`) to perform an Bluetooth advertising? Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

> Bluetooth spec "3.1.1 Legacy and extended advertising":
>
> If, since the last power-on or reset, the Host has ever issued   a
> legacy advertising command and then issues an extended   advertising
> command, or has ever issued an extended   advertising command and then
> issues a legacy advertising   command, the Controller shall return the
> error code Command   Disallowed (0x0C).

This problem occurs because the system automatically runs some extended advertising commands when starting the Bluetooth device. Start `btmod` and then run `hcitool hci0 up` and `hcitool hci0 down` commands, we can confirm this in the monitoring information.

To solve this problem, we can reset the controller by running the command: `hcitool cmd 0x03 0x0003` so that the controller can receive the legacy advertising command. After running this command, we can verify the effect by running `hcitool lescan`. Before resetting, this command will report an error: 'Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error'.

Comment: This was the exact problem and solution for me. In case anyone is wondering, the hex command shown here is sending the HCI_Reset command to the controller.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Although I can use the Reset command to reset the Bluetooth controller and start advertising.However, after the device is connected, the "parameter update command" issued by the client will not be processed, causing the connection to be disconnected after 40 seconds and an error being reported: error 34

Comment: Yes, this seems to have resolved the problem for me. I'm using it for connectionless advertising, so I'm afraid I can't help with the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your app does not have the right capabilities. Try:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw+ep' <path to your app>
```

If that does not work:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_admin+ep cap_sys_rawio+ep  cap_net_raw+ep'  <path to your app>
```